# How to add your package.json dependencies from node_modules folder?

Tags: json, node.js, gulp, node-modules

I was working on a project and **i accidentally deleted my package.json file** then i again used npm init command to create new one but i already had a lot of gulp extensions in my node_modules...

**So now how can i add those dependencies again back to my new package.json file**

How can a package.json file be get list of dependencies from my node_modules folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can alternatively list all installed dependencies using:

```
npm list --depth=0
```

and then manually add them to your package.json file

if you want to get globally installed packages, use

```
npm list -g --depth=0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @prasun, i was really stuck with it